# The text shown in the Markdown help block is rendered outside the block borders

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On both the meta and the main site, the text shown in the Markup help block goes outside the block frame, as shown in the following screenshots.

[image: english.SE screenshot]
  [image: meta.english.SE screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.